# Next JS - Deploy server in shared plan Hostinger

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hosting, nextjs-dynamic-routing, app-route

I have recently started in the world of professional web development. I recently started a project to create a website.

I created the website with Next JS v13.5.3 with App Router. The website generates dynamic routes, it is mostly created with components and also consults various data in a json file.

In development mode everything is great. The doubt comes when deploying the server. I would like to deploy it on Hostinger shared plan.

I have reviewed information on the internet for days and I have been able to find something, but all the examples generate a static website with `server.js`, without an app router, without dynamic routes and I don't know if this can work.

If anyone has achieved something similar before, it would be of great help.

Comment: Next.js is the product from vercel. They have provided a Cloud environment to deploy next.js applicatio for free directly from the GitHub repo. You can check https://vercel.com/solutions/nextjs for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can't deploy a Next.js app with all its features via Hostinger. To run Next.js, you'd need a server running Node.js, which Hostinger doesn't provide [check link](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583661-is-node-js-supported-at-hostinger)
A simple option would be to just deploy a static export: [Some features would not be supported](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports), but you can still export all your needed pages/routes at build time and make a new build and re-deploy when your content changes or you add pages.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have seen in the documentation that there would be no problem with dynamic routes.

 Now the problem is route handlers to consume a purely local API from a JSON file.

I am going to try the deployment in Hostinger and I will report in this post everything I can verify.

Again, very grateful for your response and your time.